# how to deploy to heroku from a custom branch?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have 2 apps in Heroku, one is production app and one is staging. I have configured production app remote as 'heroku' and staging app remote as 'heroku-staging' so that I can deploy to production as follows

```
git push heroku master
```

and in staging as follows:

```
git push heroku-staging master
```

Now, I want to push code to staging app from my 'staging' branch instead of master branch. I want to accomplish this

```
git push heroku-staging staging
```

If I run the above command, Heroku skips deployment saying branch is neither 'master' nor 'main' so skipping the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below command:

```
git push heroku-staging staging:master
```

When you want to go back, you can use the below command:

```
git push -f heroku master:master
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain what it does `git push heroku-staging staging:master
` ? Will it change master ?

Comment: It can be used to push from you local `staging` branch to `master` branch of your `heroku-staging` remote branch

Comment: More info : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps

Comment: Thank you. I think this is all i needed.

Comment: Glad I could help :)